# changing rotational axis

Tags: cycles-render-engine, keyframes, axis

this setup is rotating anticlockwise like a screw  (I've added the keyframes for the rotation) but now, I want to slant this set up a bit (30 degrees) when I do so, keyframed values are not working properly. I tried changing the pivot points and all, but nothing helped me. I did some research on the internet regarding this, but i cannot understand it clearly. I'm a very beginner to blender, please be kind enough to guide me through this.

-peace-

[image]

Comment: I think your question could be clearer. Please try to rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a controlling empty and use as parent.**

- Create an empty in a useful place.  Perhaps the base.
- Parent the components to the empty.  You may choose to not include any object already parented to others. Do this by selecting the children first.  Select the parent last.

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl-p</kbd>
  - Select from the pop up menu
- Rotate the empty which should rotate all the children in unison.